# What is the meaning of sarcastic?

Tags: meaning, slang, phrase-meaning

I've searched this term on internet. It shows various meanings of sarcastic which means that this word is a slang. However i just want to know the meaning of sarcastic in this very particular line

> I was trying to be sarcastic.

Comment: Its **not** slang. Please get some help in "searching." Meanwhile, please visit [ell.se]. (On a different note: It's true that *sarcasm* is not that easy to define or explain fully in simple terms.)

Comment: *sarcasm* Hindi: व्यंग्यपूर्ण, व्यंग्यमिश्रित, ताने-भरा, ... (src: Google) HTH.

Comment: I think @Harkamal Singh was trying to be facetious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't slang at all. Use the dictionaries, e.g.,

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sarcastic

will give you a pretty good coverage.

In this context, IMO it means something like

*"I was trying to sound **clever and ironical in a joking manner**."*

Comment: We have to use "comments" to post our remarks.

Comment: I have used the dictionary but didn't find my answers :(

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused in the set of meanings of this word **Sarcastic**

Comment: Urban Dictionary would not be my first choice for a reference work.

Comment: Ok i understood the meaning . Thanx :)

Comment: What does *ironical* mean here?

Comment: @ Andrew Leach Surely, but Urban D provides a lot of personal contemporary comment, helpful in such contexts:-)

Comment: @ Kris: iron·ic or iron·i·cal, both valid, per M-W U.

Comment: MariusHancu - perhaps Andrew was being sarcastic? @AndrewLeach - perhaps Marius was being sarcastic?